# Dimensions of two subspaces of a vector space not equal

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces

I have a problem to find a relationship between two subspaces of a vector space. The two subspaces are $W_1$ which is the span of $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_{n-1}\}$ and $W_2$ which is the span of $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$. Suppose $w_1 \in W_1$ and $w_2 \in W_2$. I'm trying to show that if the dimensions of $W_1$ and $W_2$ are not equal, then the number of non-zero rows in $w_1$ and $w_2$ are not equal. I argue this is true because if the dimensions are not the same then the number of vectors in the bases is not the same which means the span of the bases is not the same which is only true if the number of rows in $w_1$ and $w_2$ is not the same. Is this a valid argument?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you are trying to prove. The "number of rows"/"number of elements" in a vector doesn't really tell you anything about the dimension of a vector space. Vectors alone do not have a dimension. Vector **spaces** do have a dimension. The vectors `[1 0 0 0 0]` and `[0 1 0 0 0]` have 5 elements, but together they only span a 2 dimensional vector space. Likewise, $w_1$ and $w_2$ could both have a million elements each in some basis, but $W_1$ and $W_2$ could have different (possibly much lower) dimensions.

Comment: oops, I meant to say non-zero rows. just editted.

Comment: That is still not correct. As @eigenchris mentioned, the dimension of a vector space has nothing to do with the nonzero or zero rows of a vector in it. Do you want to say $w_1$ is a matrix consists of column vectors from $W_1$ and $w_2$ is a matrix consists of column vectors from $W_2$? And number of nonzero rows are from their row echelon forms? Even this is not true, but the question would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

question is very unclear.

you say B$_{1}$=$\left\{ v_{1},v_{2},v_{3............,}v_{n}\right\} $
and B$_{2}$=$\left\{ v_{1},v_{2},v_{3...............,}v_{n-1}\right\} $.

B$_{1}$forms basis fore W$_{1}$and B$_{2}$for W$_{2}$$\Longrightarrow$Dim$\left(W_{1}\right)$$\succ$Dim$\left(W_{2}\right)$

Then if some w$_{1}$$\epsilon W_{1}$and w$_{2}$$\epsilon$ W$_{2}$$\Longrightarrow$w$_{1}$=$\begin{pmatrix}x_{1}\\
x_{2}\\
x_{3}\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
x_{n}
\end{pmatrix}$and w$_{2}$=$\begin{pmatrix}y_{1}\\
y_{2}\\
y_{3}\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
y_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}$

it is obvious that non zero rows of w$_{1}$is greater than w$_{2}$

Comment: The OP says that $W_1$ is spanned by the set $S=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$. How does it infer that basis of $W$ is $S$?